# What is __kernel_vsyscall?

Tags: c++, gdb

I got a core that looks very different from the ones I usually get - most of the threads are in __kernel_vsyscall() :

```
  9 process 11334  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  8 process 11453  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  7 process 11454  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  6 process 11455  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  5 process 11474  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  4 process 11475  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  3 process 11476  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  2 process 11477  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  1 process 11323  0x08220782 in MyClass::myfunc ()
```

What does that mean?

EDIT:
In particular, I usually see a lot of threads in "pthread_cond_wait" and "___newselect_nocancel" and now those are on the second frame in each thread - why is this core different?

Comment: Answered in detail at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905799/having-trouble-finding-the-method-kernel-vsyscall-within-the-linux-kernel

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`__kernel_vsyscal` is the method used by linux-gate.so (a part of the Linux kernel) to make a system call using the fastest available method, preferably the `sysenter` instruction. The thing is properly explained by [Johan Petersson](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate).

Comment: the article in the link is gone :(

Comment: [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080705110028/http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/) is the snapshot that was most recent at the time of the answer:  (my desktop Waterfox throws an XML parsing error, but other browsers see it fine).

Answer (score 9):

When you make a system call (like reading from a file, talking to hardware, writing to sockets) you're actually creating an interrupt.  The system then handles the interrupt in kernel mode and your call returns with the result.  Most of the time it's unusual for you to have a lot of threads in syscall unless you're making blocking calls, in which case it's expected.

More specifically, it means the thread is waiting on a kernel level system call.  But that's (unfortunately for my points) already in the name :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already given good link to explanation of what `linux-gate.so` is, I'd like to answer "why is this core different?". Most recent (newer than 2.5.68) 32-bit Linux systems use VDSO page (aka `linux-gate.so.1`), and 64-bit systems will soon start as well (64-bit VDSO was introduced in kernel 2.6.24).

If you develop on an older system, or with an old glibc, then you would never see `__kernel_vsyscall()`, either because the kernel didn't create VDSO at all, or because (old) glibc doesn't use it even when VDSO is present.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam said, the main reason is performance. See this link for some old numbers http://lkml.org/lkml/2002/12/9/13.

If you have a vDSO enabled kernel, you're not using interrupts to run syscalls, as Stefan said, actually was because interrupts was getting slower that the whole vDSO thing was added to the kernel.