# postgres attaching a process

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, gdb

How do we attach a sql query such as join query to an existing gdb process in eclipse? Whenever I try to fork the given process using debug configurations in eclipse, which is a shared library , I am getting the following error:

**No source available for "__kernel_vsyscall() at 0xb729c424"**

Also, whenever I set break points in a specific program in eclipse, control goes to main.c and finally the process never comes back to the actual program.

Is there any way that the process be constrained only to my specific program?

Comment: This is a bit of a confused mess. What does this have to do with PostgreSQL exactly? What does *"join query to an existing gdb process in eclipse"* mean? Or *"Whenever I try to fork the given process using debug configurations in eclipse"* ? When you say *"which is a shared library"* - **what** is a shared library exactly? None of this makes any sense. I've had a wild stab in the dark at answering it, but please, try to spend a little more time thinking about how to explain your problem so we can help you properly. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/tour, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do we attach a sql query such as join query to an existing gdb process in eclipse

Um, what?

Are you attempting to debug a PostgreSQL server backend? If so, see [the PostgreSQL wiki page that provides lots of details on the topic](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD).

> Whenever I try to fork the given process using debug configurations in eclipse, which is a shared library

What is a shared library? Eclipse isn't. PostgreSQL isn't. So what's the shared library here?

Are you trying to debug a PostgreSQL extension? If so, see the above link for details on attaching to a PostgreSQL server backend.

> No source available for "__kernel_vsyscall() at 0xb729c424"

That's normal. It's just telling you that there's no source code on record for the `__kernel_vsyscall` call that's the entrypoint into syscalls in `linux-gate.so` via `glibc` when using `sysenter`.

The stack below it should be more informative. Get a backtrace, then look at the lower stack frames.

See:

- [What is __kernel_vsyscall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/344829/398670)
- [Having trouble finding the method __kernel_vsyscall within the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12905799/398670)
- http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/

Your "also" is really a separate question, and it's pretty hard to answer it usefully with the total lack of information provided. Try posting a new, more detailed question on just that topic. Specify how you compiled the program, set it up for debugging, how you're running it, where you're trying to set breakpoints, etc.