# breakpoints in eclipse using postgresql

Tags: eclipse, postgresql

I am using helios Eclipse for debugging my code in postgresql.

My aim is to know how postgresql uses join algorithms during the join query, so I started to debug **nodenestloop.c**  which is in the Executor folder.

I gave break points in that file, But whenever I try to debug that file, the control goes to main.c and never comes back,How do I constraint the control only to that particular file(nodenestloop.c)

Below are the following fields which I gave in Debug configurations of Helios Eclipse.

**C/C++ Application - src/backend/postgres** and
**project - pgsql**

I followed the steps given in the following link for running the program.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse#

I even uncheked the field "**Start on Start up=main**"  , but When I do that, The **step in and Step over** buttons are not activated and the following problem has popped up.

*Could not save master table to file '/home/ravi/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources'.
/home/ravi/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.safetable/org.eclipse.core.resources (Permission denied)*

So I started eclipse using sudo, but this time the following error has come in the console of eclipse.

*"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.*

Could any one help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: This looks like a follow-up from http://stackoverflow.com/q/24485434/398670 . How about this time if you want help you *reply to questions asking for more info*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem 1: User ID mismatch

Reading between the lines, it sounds like you're trying to debug a PostgreSQL instance that's running as the `postgres` user, or a different user ID to your own anyway. Hence your attempt to use `sudo`.

That's painful, especially when using an IDE like Eclipse. With plain `gdb` you can just `sudo` the gdb command to the desired uid, e.g. `sudo -u postgres -p 12345` to attach to pid 12345 running as user `postgres`. This will not work with Eclipse. In fact, running it with `sudo` has probably left your workspace with some messed up file permissions; run:

```
sudo chown -R ravi /home/ravi/workspace/
```

to fix file ownership.

If you want to debug processes under other user IDs with Eclipse, you'll need to figure out how to make Eclipse run `gdb` with sudo. Do *not* just run all of Eclipse with `sudo`.

### Problem 2: Trying to run PostgreSQL under the control of Eclipse

This:

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted. The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent possible system security compromise. See the documentation for more information on how to properly start the server.

suggests that you're also attempting to let Eclipse start `postgres` directly. That's very useful if you're trying to debug the *postmaster*, but since you're talking about the query planner it's clear you want to debug a particular backend. Launching the postmaster under Eclipse is useless for that, you'll be attached to the wrong process.

I think you probably need to read the documentation on PostgreSQL's internals:

- [Tour of PostgreSQL Internals](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/tour.pdf)
- [PostgreSQL internals through pictures](http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/internalpics.pdf)
- [Documentation chapter - internals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/overview.html)

### Doing it right

Here's what you need to do - rough outline, since I've only used Eclipse for Java development and do my C development with vim and gdb:

- Compile a *debug build* of PostgreSQL (compiled with `./configure --enable-debug` and preferably also `CFLAGS="-ggdb -Og -fno-omit-frame-pointer"`). Specify a `--prefix` within your homedir, like `--prefix=$HOME/postgres-debug`
- Put your debug build's `bin` directory first on your `PATH`, e.g. `export PATH=$HOME/postgres-debug/bin:$PATH`
- `initdb -U postgres -D $HOME/postgres-debug-data` a new instance of PostgreSQL from your debug build
- Start the new instance with `PGPORT=5599 pg_ctl -D $HOME/postgres-debug-data -l $HOME/postgres-debug-data.log -w start`
- Connect with `PGPORT=5599 psql postgres`
- Do whatever setup you need to do
- Get the backend process ID with `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` in a `psql` session. Leave that session open; it's the one you'll be debugging.
- Attach Eclipse's debugger to that process ID, using the Eclipse project that contains the PostgreSQL extension source code you're debugging. Make sure Eclipse is configured so it can find the PostgreSQL source code you compiled with too (no idea how to do that, see the manual).
- Set any desired breakpoints and resume execution
- In the `psql` session, do whatever you need to do to make your extension run and hit the breakpoint
- When execution pauses at the breakpoint in Eclipse, debug as desired.

### Basic misunderstandings?

Also, in case you're *really* confused about how all this works: PostgreSQL is a client/server application. If you are attempting to debug a *client program* that uses libpq or odbc, and expecting a breakpoint to trigger in some PostgreSQL backend extension code, that is not going to happen. The client application communicates with PostgreSQL over a TCP/IP socket. It's a separate program. `gdb` cannot set breakpoints in the PostgreSQL server when it's connected to the client, because they are separate programs. If you want to debug the server, you have to attach gdb to the server. PostgreSQL uses one process per connection, so you have to attach gdb to the *correct* server process. Which is why I said to use `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` above, and attach to the process ID.

See the internals documentation linked above, and:

- [PostgreSQL site - coding](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/coding/)
- [PostgreSQL wiki - developer resources](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_and_Contributor_Resources)
- [Developer FAQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ)
- [Attaching gdb to a backend on linux/bsd/unix](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue and resolved it after some struggle

I misunderstood the following point under Debugging with child processes in the wiki (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse).

5."Start postmaster & one instant of postgresql client (for creating one new postgres)"

The above step should be performed from terminal by starting postgres server and one client.

Hope this helps
Once this is done then debugger in eclipse needs to be started for **C/C++ Attach to Application**