# debugging with gdb in postgres

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, gdb

Following on from [my previous post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24594648/398670), I am trying to learn how postgresql implements the join algorithms.

So I am trying to learn about the source code of the executor precisely the file nodenestloop.c .

In the executor file I have nodenestloop.o but no binary executor file.

I am using helios eclipse to edit the source code.

I want to use gdb for debugging that file, but for that gdb needs a executor file.

I want to Debug that file using gdb and attach the postgress process file.

Could anyone help me with how to debug that file using gdb and attach a process, I know that we can find out about the pid of the process by using this command in psql, **select pg_backend_pid** , but how exactly are we going to give this pid to gdb.

any help or related links wwould be grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking how to attach to an existing process in Eclipse. This isn't really about PostgreSQL.

See this existing answer:

- [Is it possible to attach a debugging session to a running program in eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/655853/398670)

Eclipse has an "attach to application" option. Use that.